# Using Field Calculator to Symbolise point shapefiles

Tags: field-calculator, symbology

I am trying to symbolise a number of points by the species they represent. I want to group bats into one symbol and I am currently using this expression to get all the variable species and spellings that may occur:

```
"SP_GROUP" = 'Terrestrial Mammal' AND  'Bat' IN ("English") OR 'bat' IN ("English") OR 'Pipistrelle' IN ("English")OR 'Horseshoe' IN ("English") OR 'Barbastelle' IN ("English")OR 'Brown Long-eared' IN ("English")OR 'Brown Long-Eared' IN ("English")OR 'Brown Long Eared' IN ("English") OR 'BLE' IN ("English") OR 'Grey Long-eared' IN ("English") OR 'Grey Long-Eared' IN ("English") OR 'Grey Long Eared' IN ("English") OR 'GLE' IN ("English")OR 'Serotine' IN ("English")OR 'Noctule' IN ("English")OR 'Leisler' IN ("English") OR 'Nyctalus' IN ("English")OR 'Myotis' IN ("English")OR 'Bechstein' IN ("English")OR 'Natterer' IN ("English")OR 'Daubenton' IN ("English")OR 'Whiskered' IN ("English")OR 'Brandt' IN ("English")
```

The Column "ENGLISH" has all the common names in.

But it isn't working unless it is exactly how I have written it in between the apostrophes.
How can I make it so that if the cell contains any of these words anyway, but isn't 100% correct, it still outputs it?

Comment: `IN` works the other way around. You want to check, whether the current entry is in your list: `"ENGLISH" IN ('Batman','Robin','Joker','Batgirl')`.

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS. It works the way I have done it for cells that have just 'Bat' or 'Pipistrelle' but if an option is 'Common Pipistrelle' or 'Soprano Pipistrelle' it won't work. I don't want to have to input all possible options so that's why  want it to work for if it contains that specific word somewhere